# Check value from table and reward points accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

```
ReportingDirector          ManagerID       EmployeeName    EmployeeID       WeekNumber     Pointsrewarded


john(director)              1                a            11               week1           100
john(director)              1                b            22               week1           200
john(director)              1                c            33               week1           300
bob(director)               2                d            44               week1            -10
bob(director)               2                e            55               week1           30
bob(director)               2                f            66               week1           40
bob(director)               2                g            77               week1           50
bob(director)               2                h            88               week1           90
cavin(director)             3                i            99               week1           300
cavin(director)             3                j            100              week1           400
cavin(director)             3                k            111              week1           800
cavin(director)             3                l            222              week1           305
cavin(director)             3                m            333              week1           23
cavin(director)             3                n            444              week1           44
alpha (senior Director)     111              john         1111             week1           455
alpha(senior Director)      111              bob          2222             week1           -10
alpha(senior Director)      111              cavin        3333             week1            77




x                            x               mr.aplha       1               week1           99
```

I have a table above. Here we have three positions `employees`, `director` and `senior director`. Employees are under a director and director is under a senior director.

**Problem :** If any person under a director has a points (plz see `pointsReawrded` column) of -10, then the director gets -100 points, i.e add -100 points in `pointsRewarded` column for that respective director. If no employee, under him/her has -10 then the director gets a reward of 200 points.

For instance, employee 'd' in the table is under bob, who is a director. So -100 is rewarded to bob. Again, no person under john has -10 , so john gets a reward of 200 points.

We don't reward any points to 'alpha' even if any employee under him has a points of -10 as he is at the top of the chain.

Can anyone help me with a generalized query to check if any employee under a director has a score of -10 and penaltize that director a score of -100 points. If not a reward of 200 points.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Please give us a look into code that you've already tried with

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
    ;with cte as
(
  select ReportingDirector, ManagerID, EmployeeName, EmployeeID, WeekNumber, Pointsrewarded
  ,COUNT(IIF(Pointsrewarded < 0,0,null))
over (partition by ReportingDirector order by ReportingDirector) as grp
  from #tmp1
  where ReportingDirector = ''
  UNION ALL
  select a.ReportingDirector, a.ManagerID, a.EmployeeName, a.EmployeeID, a.WeekNumber, a.Pointsrewarded
  ,COUNT(IIF(a.Pointsrewarded < 0,0,null))
over (partition by a.ReportingDirector order by a.ReportingDirector) as grp
  FROM #tmp1 a
  join cte on a.ManagerID = cte.EmployeeID 
)
select cte.*, IIF(grp = 1, -100,200) MgrPointsRewarded
from cte
where ReportingDirector <> ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the input  - (director) is just to let you guys know .It wont be there in the db ,ofcourse.